# How can I execute hadoop distcp -f command properly?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, hadoop2, distcp

I want to get backup, on my hadoop cluster, for some folders and files. I ran this command:

```
hadoop distcp -p -update -f hdfs://cluster1:8020/srclist hdfs://cluster2:8020/hdpBackup/
```

My srclist file :

```
hdfs://cluster1:8020/user/user1/folder1
hdfs://cluster1:8020/user/user1/folder2
hdfs://cluster1:8020/user/user1/file1
```

`folder1` contains two files : `part-00000 and part-00001`

`folder2` contains two files : `file and file_old`

That command works but explodes all folders contents.

Result :

```
--hdpBackup
  - part-00000
  - part-00001
  - file1
  - file
  - file_old
```

But I want to get result :

```
--hdpBackup
  - folder1
  - folder2
  - file1
```

I can not use hdfs://cluster1:8020/user/user1/* because user1 contains many folders and files.

How can I solve this problem ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the script below, it is shell programming:

```
 #!/bin/sh

 for line in `awk '{print $1}' /home/Desktop/distcp/srclist`;
 do
 line1=$(echo $line | awk 'BEGIN{FS="/"}{print $NF}')

 echo "$line  $line1 file are source dest" 

 hadoop distcp  $line hdfs://10.20.53.157/user/root/backup1/$line1

 done
```

`srclist` file needs to be in the local file system contails paths like:

```
   hdfs://10.20.53.157/user/root/Wholefileexaple_1
   hdfs://10.20.53.157/user/root/Wholefileexaple_2
```

Comment: I would be curious about performance. The way I would see your solution, it would spawn a JVM for each loop iteration.